If i do not have any backup, can i still try to restore a voice message sent to my WhatsApp and then it was deleted by the sender
I have iPhone 11 with latest IOS version 17.6.1. And I received 3 voices messages from one of my contracts around 3 months ago. and I listen to them at that time. I thought they will stay on my iPhone. But today when I tried to listen to them back, I got that This Message was deleted, I tried to call the sender but seems he changed his number. As i remember that I did not delete them so most probably they were deleted by the sender. So is there a way to try to recover those voice messages? I google this, and I found many tools but not sure if they are trusted? any recommendation or advice?
I know that those 3rd part recovery tools will access everything on my iPhone, so I need to be sure that no data will leaked. So for example is there a recovery tool I can use which I can connect it to my iPhone, then remove it from my PC and also i can run it without internet connection, so i will be sure that no data will be transferred out of my iPhone?
Thanks

It's been a while since I used WhatsApp, but I thought it made backups on the phone?

@MarcWilson thanks for the reply. no i disable the option to save the messages on my iphone to save space

They're gone, then.

@MarcWilson but since they were inside my iphone , so cannot i use 3rd party tools to recover deleted files in general and from whatsapp specifically ?

No. Recovering data from SSDs is near impossible. Backups are essential.

@benwiggy I know it might be hard, that why  i am saying if there is a tool to try.. i remember 10 years ago i deleted all the images from my digital camera by mistake, and i were able to recover them using a toool
